# Delete files from github

Tags: github, github-for-windows

So I forgot to setup a .gitignore before doing my commit and now I have some files in the git I'd rather not be on a public repo. I've checked the site and I can't find where to delete some files. Now I've made a git ignore it no longer updates those files. But they are still there. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Comment: Nope. Mine doesn't show in the status. But the files are still in GitHub repo because they were commited but now I want them uncommitted lol

Comment: You can push another commit removing them or remove them and [amend the existing commit.](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---amend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a help article from github that should include the answer to your question
https://help.github.com/en/articles/deleting-files

Comment: glad to be of help :)